# How can I speed up Python performance using Cython vs C extension

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm trying to speed up the performance of this method in Python.

```
    def get_legal_actions(self):
        legalActions = set([])

        add = legalActions.add
        items = dict.items
        state = self.state
        immutableProps = self.immutableProps

        for action, definition in items(self.allActions):

            legal = True
            for pre, targetValue in items(definition["precondition"]):
                try:
                    if state[pre] != targetValue:
                        legal = False
                        break
                except KeyError:
                    if pre not in immutableProps:
                        legal = False
                        break

            if legal: add(action)

        return legalActions
```

Currently with a size of ~500000 for allActions it runs in ~0.23 seconds. However, I'm gonna need to call this method at least a million of times, so it is not fast enough.

Then, I tried to implement this method with Cython.

```
cpdef list get_legal_actions(dict state, frozenset immutableProps, dict allActions):
    cdef list legalActions = []
    cdef int legal

    append = legalActions.append
    items = dict.items

    for action, definition in items(allActions):

        legal = 0

        for pre, targetValue in items(definition["precondition"]):
            try:
                if state[pre] != targetValue:
                    legal = 1
                    break
            except KeyError:
                if pre not in immutableProps:
                    legal = 1
                    break

        if legal == 0: append(action)

    return legalActions
```

This time, with the same configuration, it runs in ~0.15 seconds (a small improvement but not enough). Is there a way to improve this?

Lastly, I tried with a C extension hoping that it would speed up the performance even more.

```
static PyObject* exmod_get_legal_actions(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  PyObject *state, *allActions, *immutableProps;
  PyObject *legalActions = PySet_New(NULL);

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOO", &state, &immutableProps, &allActions)) return NULL;

  PyObject *action, *definition, *pre, *targetValue, *stateValue;
  Py_ssize_t pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0;
  int legal;

  while (PyDict_Next(allActions, &pos1, &action, &definition))
  {
    legal = 1;  // True
    pos2 = 0;
    while (PyDict_Next(PyDict_GetItemString(definition, "precondition"), &pos2, &pre, &targetValue))
    {
      stateValue = PyDict_GetItem(state, pre);

      if ((stateValue == NULL && PySet_Contains(immutableProps, pre) != 1) ||  // If pre not in state and pre is not found in immutableProps
          (stateValue != NULL && PyObject_RichCompareBool(PyDict_GetItem(state, pre), targetValue, Py_EQ) == 0))  // If pre in state and it is False that they are equal
      {
        legal = 0;  // False
        break;
      }
    }

    if (legal == 1) PySet_Add(legalActions, action);
  }

  return Py_BuildValue("O", legalActions);
}
```

However, it's a bit slower (~0.18 seconds).

It's the first time I implement something using Cython or a C extension so I don't really know why the C extension is not the fastest option. Maybe is because I'm working with PyObjects? Would it be faster to implement the extension without using PyDicts and all those functions? If so, how can I do it in C? A code example of how to work with Python dictionaries in C would be appreciated.

Comment: Odd, you're trying to micro-optimize (I guess) access to `dict.items`, but call `definition["precondition"]` repeatedly. Did you profile this? Further, using `else` after the inner `for`-loop would eliminate a temporary flag and it would be much more elegant. Another thing that strikes me is that you build and return a set, why isn't that function a generator, which can be way more efficient?

Comment: You seem to have unrealistic expectations for what is achievable.  Your method processes *half a million* "actions" on each call.  The Cython version takes only 300 nanoseconds for each one.  There's not a lot of room to work with, here.  At your current speed, it will take about two days to process a million calls.  You don't say how fast you need to go, but shrinking that to, say, half an hour would be a speed increase of two orders of magnitude.  The only way I see that happening is massive parallelization.

Comment: Cython specifically optimizes for loops over `dict.items`. I'm reasonably sure your attempt at micro-optimizing it will actually break this Cython optimization. Even so I agree with the general consensus that what you're asking doesn't look plausible